# [unix server]I want to check the specific directory size including its all children

Tags: unix, sunos

This is the server info(`uname -a`)

```
SunOS Tiger2 5.7 Generic_106541-16 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-Enterprise
```

And I want to check some directory size including its all children directories. 
I fount `du -sh /some` command, but it doesn't work.

My server says `-h` is invalid. 
I guess it's too old maybe.

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `man du`.  I believe you'll find `du -sk /some` will give you the summary size in kilobytes.  Omit the `k` and it will be in 0.5 KiB blocks.  Omit the `-s` and it will give you the size of each directory (and its descendents) as it processes it.  If you try to use options that are not supported, expect to get messages about invalid options.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to find which directory is going insane with size, try

```
cd ${mountPointDirWhereThingsAreGettingTooTight}
du -s * | sort -n
.....
62719   usr
4043953 Pictures
4703272 AppData
5193812 VirtualBox VMs
8117498 Downloads
```

Then, if 1 directory stands out as way over-sized, you can `cd` into that dir and repeat the `du ...` and repeat until to locate the exact problem.

You can add `| tail -20` or similar to reduce the output.

Many systems support `k`, `m` options to indicate results in Kilobytes or Megabytes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `du -bc` and check the last line of the output. Note that `du` provides just a raw estimate.

Comment: Hm... it says `-b` is also invalid.

Comment: Would you give me a tip? I just need to roughly check its size.

Comment: @Deckard: then use just `du -c` to get the total and look up in `du(1)` what exactly it's reporting; I think it's disk blocksize or something, so you'll may have to do some arithmetic to get kBs. Or install the GNU shell utilities, those have all the options you need (and many more).